# how to set minimum and maximum of polar plots

Tags: vba, excel, polar-coordinates

Hi This code runs but does not update my polar plot based on the values set in my variables myXmin and myXmax. Any thoughts on how to properly update the min/max of a polar plot?

```
Dim cht as Chart
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chname1).Chart
With cht.Axes(xlValue)
.MinimumScale = myXmin
.MaximumScale = myXmax
 End with
```

Comment: start macro record, adjust the min/max manually, stop macro record and check the resulting code

Answer (score 0):

Change xlvalue to xlCategory

```
With cht.Axes(xlCategory)
```

Comment: I tried this but did not work.. It errored at .MinimumScale = myXmin...                           The xlValue at least did not debug but didn't work.